# Find the limits of integration of $f(x,y)$ using polar coordinates over the following Domain $D=\{(x,y):4x\leq x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 5x\}$.

Tags: integration

So, it's given on this question the domain $D=\{(x,y):4x\leq x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 5x\}$. It also said that we use polar coordinates of the form $$x=R\cos t$$ and $$y=R\sin t$$ then we have to find the limits of integration of the double integral over this domain. I'm kind of confused because I thought the limits would be $2$ and $5/2$ for the outsider integral relative to $dr$, and $0$ to $2\pi$ on the insider integral relative do dt. But both of those answers are wrong and I'm having trouble finding why. Visual approaches still let me confuse with double integrals over domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at this region. $4x\le x^2 + y^2 \le 5x$

Start with $x^2+y^2 = 5x$

$(x^2 - 5x) + y^2 = 0\\
(x^2 - 5x + (\frac {5}{2})^2) + y^2 = (\frac {5}{2})^2\\
(x^2 - \frac {5}{2})^2 + y^2 = (\frac {5}{2})^2$

It is a circle centered $\frac {5}{2}$ units from the orgin, of radius $\frac 52$ units.  The origin lies on the circle.

And $x^2 + y^2 = 4x$ is a circle centered $2$ units from the origin, of radius $2$ units.

The region we are interested in is a little crescent between the two circles.  The reason to do this analysis and have a picture of what we are working with is that it tells us that the entire region is to the right of the y axis.

Now for an approach that is raw algebra.

$x = r\cos\theta\\
y = r\sin\theta\\
r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Now state your region in terms of $r$ and $\theta.$

$4r\cos\theta \le r^2\le 5r\cos\theta$

Since $r\ge 0$ we can safely divide through by $r.$

$4\cos\theta \le r\le 5\cos\theta$

And we have our limits for $r.$

$\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \int_{4\cos\theta}^{5\cos\theta}  f(r,\theta) r\ dr\ d\theta$

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$x^2+y^2-5x\le0$$
$$(x-5/2)^2-25/4+y^2\le0$$
$$(x-5/2)^2+y^2\le25/4$$
and you have:
$$x^2+y^2-4x\ge 0$$
$$(x-2)^2-4+y^2\ge0$$
$$(x-2)^2+y^2\ge 4$$
So your region can be represented as the inside of a circle centre $(5/2,0)$ and radius $5/2$ and the outside of a circle centre $(2,0)$ and radius $2$. If you sketch these graphs you will notice that one is inside the other, so your region looks something like an uneven ring donut. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's repeat @HenryLee's reasoning in polar coordinates. We have $4R\cos t\le R^2\le5R\cos t$, i.e. $4\cos t\le R\le5\cos t$. At least one $R$ satisfies this iff $\cos t\ge0$, so it's convenient to give $t$ a range on which this condition is satisfied contiguously. In particular we take $t\in[-\pi,\,\pi]$, so in $D$ this is limited to $t\in[-\pi/2,\,\pi/2]$. For a function $f$, $\iint_Dfdxdy=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}dt\int_{4\cos t}^{5\cos t}RfdR$.